# How do I run hook_views_data_alter()?

Tags: views, 8, hooks

So I have already read and followed everything I could find on that issue:

1. putting my_module_views_data_alter(array &$data) in my_module.views.inc file in the root directory of my_module,
2. disabling cache for my view,
3. clearing caches million times,

but still I can never stop at a breakpoint inside this hook, nor can I see any effects of the code I have put in it.

What am I missing?

**EDIT: updating with some code**

In my_module I have already created a computed field user_age, calculating user age from a custom user profile field with date of birth.

**my_module/my_module.module**

```
function my_module_entity_base_field_info(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  if ($entity_type->id() === 'user') {
    $fields = [];
    $fields['user_age'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('user_age_field')
      ->setName('user_age')
      ->setLabel(t('User age'))
      ->setComputed(TRUE)
      ->setClass('\Drupal\my_module\UserAgeIntegerItemList')
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'label' => 'hidden',
        'weight' => -5,
      ]);

    return $fields;
  }
}
function my_module_field_formatter_info_alter(array &$info) {
  $info['number_integer']['field_types'][] = 'user_age_field';
}
```

This field is working and is accessible in my user profile template.

Knowing that since Drupal 8.4

> Computed fields can now be displayed by Views

I wanted to use field user_age as an exposed filter in my search_users view:

**my_module/my_module.views.inc**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter().
 */
function my_module_views_data_alter(array &$data) {
  if (isset($data['users_field_data'])) {
    $data['users_field_data']['user_age'] = [
      'title' => t('User age'),
      'field' => [
        'id' => 'my_module_view_user_age',
      ],
    ];
  }
}
```

**my_module/src/Plugin/views/field/MyModuleViewUserAge.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\views\field;

use Drupal\views\ResultRow;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\FieldPluginBase;

/**
 * A handler to provide proper displays for user user_age.
 *
 * @ingroup views_field_handlers
 *
 * @ViewsField("my_module_view_user_age")
 */
class MyModuleViewUserAge extends FieldPluginBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function render(ResultRow $values) {
    $relationship_entities = $values->_relationship_entities;
    $age = '';
    // First check the referenced entity.
    if (isset($relationship_entities['user'])) {
      $user = $relationship_entities['user'];
    }
    else {
      $user = $values->_entity;
    }

    $type = get_class($user);
    if ($type === 'Drupal\user\Entity\User') {
      $age = $user->get('user_age')->getvalue();
    }

    return $age;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function query() {
    // This function exists to override parent query function.
    // Do nothing.
  }
}
```

but my_module_views_data_alter() seems to never be executed and user_age field is not present in the filter criteria for my view.

Comment: It doesn't need to go into a .view.inc file. Try placing your code in my_module.module and flushing the caches

Comment: It went there after being in my_module.module first and not working there either :)

Comment: either place your code to `my_module.module` or just load your `.inc` file inside your module like 
`module_load_include('inc', 'my_module', 'my_module.views');`

Comment: Have you enabled your custom module? An easy thing to forget if you're trying new things out

Comment: my_module is enabled. This hook was not working in .module file, and is not working in .inc loaded with module_load_include. But if I add a random function to my .inc file I can stop at a breakpoint in it. Just not at the breakpoint in hook_views_data_alter(). When exactly is this hook supposed to fire?

Comment: It should get triggered when a view is going to be rendered to allow you to altered the results data in view. So if you dont have any views rendering then it wouldnt get triggered. You could update your question with your code using that function that might help people answer

Comment: I have updated my question as you suggested.

Comment: Have you tried to remove this condition ? isset($data['users_field_data'])

Answer (score 4):

You can't xdebug in hook itself, you need to go to method calling this hooks which is in **class ViewsData**  path /core/modules/views/src/ViewsData.php
and put breakpoint in getData, clear cache and you will get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

we should empty cache_default table.
The only way I know is by MYSQL "**TRUNCATE cache_default**"

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example MYMODULE.views.inc I've used recently in a module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data().
 */
function MYMODULE_views_data() {

  $data['schema_name']['nid'] = [
    'title' => t('NID'),
    'help' => t('NID from schema_name'),
    'field' => [
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_numeric',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
      'float' => TRUE,
      'id' => 'numeric',
    ],
    'relationship' => [
      'title' => 'NID',
      'label' => t('NID'),
      'help' => t('NID from schema_name'),
      'id' => 'standard',
      'base' => 'node',
      'base field' => 'nid',
      'relationship field' => 'nid',
      'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
    ],
    'sort' => [
      'id' => 'standard',
    ],
    'filter' => [
      'id' => 'numeric',
    ],
    'argument' => [
      'id' => 'numeric',
    ],
  ];

  return $data;

}
```

Some things I don't see in your code:

1. no `handler` for the views field
2. no `filter` or `sort` key for your field
3. not printing `return $data;` in your views.inc file

I know this is not a *direct answer*, but hoping it helps.

Comment: The handler was the last part of the code in my question. hook_views_data_alter() uses &$data, so no returns there, and I did not use hook_views_data(), because I don't think I need to define any relationships for my field at this point (or do I, because otherwise I will not get this running at all?).
Even if I use hook_views_data() it still won't ever stop at a breakpoint in it.